# Spring - pass parameters through link

Tags: java, spring, hyperlink, parameters, request

Suppose I have a list of objects in a Spring web application view. Suppose these objects are forum threads. Each of them has a link, which will move to the page with all topics for this thread. Now in order to list those topics, I will need to retain the thread id which was selected. Part of the .jsp that contains the link:

```
<h3><spring:message code="label.threadList"/></h3>
<c:if  test="${!empty threadList}">
<table class="data">
<tr>
    <th><spring:message code="label.threadName"/></th>
     <th><spring:message code="label.threadDescription"/></th>
    <th><spring:message code="label.threadTopicCount"/></th>
    <th><spring:message code="label.threadLastModified"/></th>
    <th>Go</th>

</tr>
<c:forEach items="${threadList}" var="thread">
    <tr>
        <td>${thread.name} </td>
        <td>${thread.description} </td>
        <td>${thread.topics}</td>
        <td>${thread.last_modified}</td>
        <td><a href="topics.html">Open</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Now, from what I understand, I will need to take the param by request mapping:

```
@Controller
public class TopicPageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/topics", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(@RequestParam("getId") int getId) {

        System.out.println(getId); //here's when I want to see the param
        return new ModelAndView();
    }
}
```

What I can't get right, is passing it. How can I include, that on clicking this link, the request will get that parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the id to the link:

```
 <td><a href="topics.html?getId=${thread.id}">Open</a></td>
```